# why tmp_name is used in this example

Tags: php, file, upload

I am quite new to php.I was going through an example on file uploading.Here inside `getimagesize()` function `$_FILES['file']['temp_name']` is used.and when i echoed $_FILES['file']['temp_name'] it shows the following output:

> C:\xampp\tmp\phpDE4B.tmp

my questions are:

1.why use tmp_name instead of original name inside `getimagesize()` function.

2.For what reason this tmp_name is created ?

3.How it is generated?

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a temporary directory name where PHP uploads the image, before you move it to another folder. Otherwise, it will get deleted.

Comment: what do you mean by another folder??

Comment: You must move it to another folder,  using. [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary file is generated as part of the file upload process, handled directly between PHP and the web server.

A temp file is used so that userland code can move the file to its final destination folder on the server - the final destination folder isn't information that can be passed in the http request, or handled by the web server, because it depends entirely on your application. If the file isn't moved to its final destination folder, then the temporary file will be deleted automatically at the end of the request

In this case, the code is part of a validation process to ensure that the file is what it claims to be ***before*** moving it to its final destination folder (assuming that it is a valid file).

Comment: Wit regards to question #3, PHP decides where to put the file, but this can be controlled in php.ini with this config: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: if i get it right ,the thing going on here is the image i upload for temporary use will be copied temporarily in the server and can be accessed via  tmp_name.After closing the script it will be deleated from the server.Is that it????

Comment: As far as the code you've posted goes, yes it will simply be deleted afterwards... typically, you'd use move_uploaded_file() to move the temp file to its final destination if it passed validation, or return an error message and leave it to be automatically deleted if it failed

Answer (score 1):

When some file is uploaded to the server, it is placed in temporary directory to work with it. In order to not have collisions in names temporary name is assigned.

1) You need to pass the path to file to `getimagesize()`, because you can want to work not only with saved files.

2) Tmp_name is created to avoid collisions, but you can get original name if you need.

3) Just some random generated name inside of a temp directory.

Comment: "tmp_name" is created to avoid collision"--can you describe it in a few words??