# Original path for PHP image upload

Tags: php, image-upload

I was looking for a good image upload plugin for CakePHP2 and found these ones:

- https://github.com/angelitomg/QimageComponent
- https://github.com/BradCrumb/CakeImageCropResize (my preference)

Both image uploads needs a $imagePath and a potential options array. Am I right that $imagePath should always be a path to an image on the server? Why can't it be the temporary image path (e.g. C:\xampp\tmp\php8454.tmp)?

Comment: See this info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28528611/715105

Comment: The strange thing is that those 2 plugins ask me to use a file on the server. If I use the temp image name, the script uses the file type '.tmp' to save the generated thumbnail. So I wondered if that's the way it should always / best be?